# Trouble exporting (and then importing) .db files correctly in SQLiteStudio

Tags: database, sqlite, sqlitestudio

I created it the database SQLite Studio and need to export it into a db file.
But this always pops up. It says: It cannot be exported to the file XXtest7. The file cannot be opened for write access.

Hello,

I have a problem exporting my database. I created it on SQLite Studio and need to export it into a db file.

But this always pops up. It says: It cannot be exported to the file XXtest7. The file cannot be opened for write access.

I have to sumbit it today so I am thankful for any help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of exporting simply save the file, make a copy with whatever file name you wish.

An SQLite database is a single file (assuming the database has been closed) and it can be copied renamed. SQLite itself manages the file (or files).

- If **W**rite **A**head **L**ogging is used then the `-wal` file, if it exists (it shouldn't if the main file has been closed correctly) then that file is part of the database. see https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html

`Exporting` is extracting the data from the database in another format (as allowed by the tool's options) it will NOT be an SQLite Database file.

---

**As a simple example:-**

---

1. A new database is added location being `.../SQliteStudio Databases/mydatabase.sqlite`.
2. A single table name `mytable` with 2 columns is created:- [image]
3. the connection is closed and the file is saved as `mydatabase.sqlite` and the connection re-opened.
   4.Tool/Export is used for types HTML,JSON,SQL and XML *(e.g. for XML)*:- [image]

   1. Note the file path and the new file name
4. After closing the connection (to fully commit the WAL file should it exist) then file explorer is used to `copy` the file, paste it and rename the pasted file to `XXTest7.xxx`.

   1. all files have been saved to the same directory folder
5. In Windows Explorer:- [image]

- The first file mydatabase.sqlite is the actual sqlite database file as created and maintained by `SQlite Studio`
- `XXTest7.xxx` is  the copied and renamed version of the file.
- XXTest7_exported.html is the export using HTML and looks like:- [image]
- `XXTest7.JSON`
  :- [image]
- `XXTest7.sql` :- [image]
- XXTest7.xml` :- [image]

SO the EXPORTED files are just files that could be imported into an sqlite database **given an appropriate tool to do so**.

Files `mydatabase.sqlite` and `XXTest7.xxx` if opened using NotePad++ looks like:- [image] ***not of much use***.

However if opened via SQLite (either a tool or via the SQLite programming interface) the database is as per the original. e.g. Connecting to the `XXTest7.xxx`  file using DBeaver results in :-
[image]